# Computing transition probabilities and invariant distributions

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

Suppose $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geq 0}$ is a Markov chain with state space $I=\{1,2,\dots,6\}$ and transition matrix
$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{1}{10} \\
 0 & \frac{7}{10} & 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{10} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & \frac{9}{10} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{10} & 0 & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{7}{10} & 0 \\
 \frac{3}{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{7}{10} \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

I need to find all the invariant distributions and the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n=2\mid X_0=1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{1,2}^{(n)}$.

To find the invariant distributions I solved the system
$$\begin{cases}\pi P=\pi\\\pi_1+\pi_2+\pi_3+\pi_4+\pi_5+\pi_6=1\end{cases}$$
and I got $\pi=(0,\pi_2,1-4\pi_2,2\pi_2, \pi_2, 0)$. It seems to work but I want to know if there is a shorter way of computing this solution that doesn't involve solving 7 linear equations. Also, is $\pi_1=\pi_6=0$ because $\{1,6\}$ is an open class? Is it always true that if state $i$ is in an open class and there exist a non-trivial invariant distribution $\pi$ then $\pi_i=0$?

For computing the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{1,2}^{(n)}$ I tried using the fact that the class $\{1,6\}$ is open and $\{2,4,5\}$ is closed, but I am not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*before doing any calculations:*
break this down to irreducibles.  I see $\big\{3\big\}$ and $\big\{2,4,5\big\}$ as recurrent classes and 1 and 6 being transient states. (You can group them together since they communicate but what matters is that they are transient.)   This implies $\dim \ker (P-I)=2$ i.e. one Perron root ($=1$) for each recurrent class.

Now solve for the Perron vector (stationary distribution after re-scaling) for each recurrent irreducibles.
$\big\{3\big\}$ has (standard basis vector) $\mathbf e_3$ as stationary by inspection.
$\big\{2,4,5\big\}$ needs solved.  So take your matrix and delete rows and columns 6, 3, and 1 and call the resulting matrix $B$. Note: $B$ has a positive diagonal so it must be aperiodic.  Now use gaussian elimination or whatever you like to build a basis for $\ker B^T$ (it's 1 dimensional and has your Perron vector $\mathbf v$).  Now rescale so Perron vector is non-negative and sums to 1.  All this took was manipulating 3 linear equations which is doable.

Now do zero padding so that $\mathbf v$ is compatable with your original matrix.   i.e. $\mathbf v':= \left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 \\ v_1 \\ 0 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right)$

you have $P\mathbf v' = \mathbf v'$ and $P \mathbf e_3 = \mathbf e_3$.  And any *convex* combination of the two gives another steady probability vector (probability vectors are real non-negative and sum to one so we can't do arbitrary linear combinations but instead do convex combinations).

**Finally**
for $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n=2\mid X_0=1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{1,2}^{(n)}$
check that state 6 never directly enters a recurrent class-- given a start in state 1 the only way of exiting a transient state is given by row one of your matrix.

the probability of entering state 3 is $\frac{1}{10}$ and entering  $\big\{2,4,5\big\}$ =$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{3}{10}$ (and probability $\frac{6}{10}$ you have to repeat the experiment), which implies $p=\frac{3}{4}$ exit to $\big\{2,4,5\big\}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ to 3.  Thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n=2\mid X_0=1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}p_{1,2}^{(n)} = \frac{3}{4}\times \text{ 2nd component of }\mathbf v'$.  (This final bit makes use of the fact that $B$ i.e. $\big\{2,4,5\big\}$ is aperiodic... if said class had period $\geq 2$ the limit technically wouldn't exist.)

Comment: Thank you! That's such an excellent answer. In the last part, we can ignore the probability of staying in $\{1,6\}$ because it is transient and so it is ultimately 0?

Comment: Right.  Another way to look at it is probability of entering $\big\{2,4,5\big\}$ is given by a geometric series $p = \frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{10}\big(\frac{6}{10}\big) + \frac{3}{10}\big(\frac{6}{10}\big)^2 + ... = \frac{3}{10} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty \big(\frac{6}{10}\big)^k =\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{6}{10}} =\frac{3}{10}\cdot \frac{10}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$